# x-editable - On input focus, select all text?

Tags: jquery, forms, user-interface, x-editable

I want to select (highlight all) text when the user selects a text box (on input focus) with x-editable? Standard solutions don't work, because the editable input doesn't exist in the DOM.

JS

```
$('.class-foo').editable({
    showbuttons: false,
    mode: 'inline'
})
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="id-foo" data-type="text" class="editable editable-click editable-empty"></a></td>
```

Answer (score 2):

Appending this code to the editable tag solves the problem for x-editable.

```
$('#id-foo').editable({
    showbuttons: false,
    mode: 'inline'
}).on('shown', function(ev, editable) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        editable.input.$input.select();
    },0);
});
```

Credit to [mnpenner](https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable/issues/330)